# How can I create a drop-down table of contents in Word 2021?

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting, table-of-contents

How can I create a drop-down table of contents in Word 2021?

I know how to create a standard table of contents in Word, but since the file I'm working on is composed of three parts, which in turn contain chapters, I wanted to create a drop-down option. The file is supposed to be published on Amazon Kindle, so the chapters will have to be clickable.

On the internet, I only found how to create drop-down lists, not table of contents.

Comment: Do you mean a collapsible TOC that you can fold up? So 1.1 would normally show 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3, but can be collapsed to just show the heading 1/heading  2 level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create a drop-down list that contains hyper-links
to parts of your document. This is to be done manually and cannot
be automated.
The drop-down list may contain any text that you like.

In addition, you will need to create a VBA macro that will detect
changes in the drop-down list, check the selected entry,
and do the jump.

This is a heavy solution that requires that the spreadsheet be stored
as a macro-enabled `.docm` file.

Some pointers to start you on the way if you decide :

- [Run a Macro from a Drop Down list [VBA]](https://www.get-digital-help.com/run-a-macro-from-a-drop-down-list-vba/)
- [Link text field to dropdown list](https://www.msofficeforums.com/word/27863-link-text-field-dropdown-list.html)
- [Hyperlinking options in dropdown list in Word](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/hyperlinking-options-in-dropdown-list-in-word/007ffae8-5996-42ea-9851-8e2168df1b12)

Comment: Not .xlsm but .docm?

Comment: @CharlesKenyon: I corrected the error.

Answer (score 1):

### I have no reason to think this will translate to Kindle

1. Create your TOC using only styles and/or TC fields, not outline
   levels.
2. Assign Outline Levels to the TOC styles.

This will allow the expand/collapse headings feature to work with your TOC. This feature was introduced in Word 2013.